# Use of "async" has been depreciated. Alternative to make synchronous call in ajax/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to return some data after post request and keep in a local variable to use multiple times. I have written below code which returns undefined everytime.

```
function getSomeList()
{
    var myVariable;
    $.post("/Home/getList", { 'input': inputData })
  .done(function (data) {
      //alert("Data Loaded: " + data); // I can see the data here.
      myVariable = data;
  });
  return myVariable;
}
```

If call this function then it returns undefined.

```
  alert(getSomeList());
```

I also tried with old way by writing async: false and came to know that Use of "async" has been depreciated.

```
$.ajax({
    'async': false,
    'type': "POST",
    .
    .
    .
});
```

Please let me know if there is any other solution.

Comment: `alert(data)` inside the done callback.

Comment: Your function returns `myVariable` right away instead of waiting for the request to finish. This is why it returns undefined. You should take a look at deferreds from jQuery, which are pretty similar to Promises from es6.

Comment: @Taplar As mentioned in comment, I can see the data in done callback.

Comment: Right, because the logic is asynchronous.  To code with asynchronous logic, you have to change how you approach the issue, and use the methods that accommodate that different paradigm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the callbacks that are within the paradigm of asynchronous processing.

```
function getSomeList(inputData) {
  return $.post("/Home/getList", { 'input': inputData });
}

getSomeList(missingVariable).then(function(data){
  alert(data);
});
```

If you need to use the value some time later in your application, you can store the promise and use it later.

```
someSharedVariable = getSomeList(missingVariable);

... other lines of code ...

... future point in time ...
someSharedVariable.then(function(data){
  //use data in your secondary ajax call
});
```

Comment: I tried this logic but the output is same. I can see the data in alert but can not store in a global variable and reuse it. Still getting "undefined".

Comment: Right, you don't want to use a global variable, because the "end" of an asynchronous method is in determinant.  If you need a value off the response of an ajax call, you need to use one of the callbacks to get it.  You could optionally store the response of the `getSomeList()` in the global variable, and any time you need to use the response, pop another `then()` on it.

Comment: Also it should be noted that synchronous requests have only been deprecated in jQuery.  javascript still supports them with passing in false on the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open

Comment: I need to store it because I have to pass the response of this method in another ajax call as a input parameter. I am trying to follow your approach but no luck.If I store the response of the getSomeList() in the global variable use another then() than it returns object not the actual response.